# Calling a method on a static class given its type name and method names as strings

Tags: c#, reflection

How could I go about calling a method on a static class given the class name and the method name, please?

For example:

Given `System.Environment` and `GetFolderPath`, I'd like to use `Reflection` to call `Environment.GetFolderPath()`.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Just

```
Type.GetType(typeName).GetMethod(methodName).Invoke(null, arguments);
```

where `typeName` is the name of the type as a string, `methodName` is the name of the method as a string, and `arguments` is an array of objects containing the arguments to call the method with.

Comment: Wow, ok yeah that works - didn't know about Type.GetType - just make sure that the Static class name is fully qualified with the namespace

Comment: @GeorgeMauer what if there is no namespace?

Comment: @MonsterMMORPG Unity3d? I certainly have never tried it but you can try a) not using a namespace at all or b) `"global::NameOfClass"`. Also it might be only a single `:`. I don't remember

Comment: If you're trying to call functions from string inside own static class, like I was, (ex: console application with a lot of functions inside Program.cs, and you want to have a var controlling which function to call), you could use `typeof(Program).GetMethod($"F{functionNumber}").Invoke(null, null);` inside Main(), with a variable named functionNumber to call them, and with your methods named F1(), F2(), F3()...

Answer (score 6):

First you need to get the Type (by iterating on the assembly using reflection)

see this link for details: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.propertyinfo.aspx

or use

```
Assembly.GetType
```

once you have the type in hand you can iterate over members using reflection or

```
MethodInfo method = typeof(MyClass).GetMethod("MyMethod");
```

then you can use `MethodInfo.Invoke` and pass arguments to invoke the method when you want to invoke it.

Comment: **MyClass** is public, not way for  ***`internal static class`*** ?

Comment: @Kiquenet Internal static class should work using `MethodInfo methodInfo = typeof(InternalStaticClassName).GetMethod("PrivateMethodNameYouWantToCall", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static);` and then invoke it passing `null` as the target object and an object array of whatever parameters you need.

Answer (score 3):

```
System.Reflection.Assembly info = typeof(System.Environment).Assembly;

Type t = info.GetType("System.Environment");
MethodInfo m = t.GetMethod("GetFolderPath");

object result = m.Invoke(null, arguments);
```

Answer (score 3):

What you are doing here is reflecting on the type named `Environment` and using the `GetPropery` and `GetGetMethod` methods to get the get method of the `Environment.CurrentDirectory` property like so;

```
var getMethod = typeof(Environment).GetProperty("CurentDirectory", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static).GetGetMethod();
var currentDirectory = (string)getMethod.Invoke(null, null);
```

Calling the get method of a property returns it's value and is equivilent to;

```
var value = Environment.CurrentDirectory;
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a basic outline of what you would do:

1. Scan all the objects in the current AppDomain - find the one that matches what you know the class name to be
2. Get the static method with the name you know on that object
3. Dynamically invoke it.

**Edit:**  This will work if you do not know the namespace of the static class.  Otherwise use Daniel Brückner's solution as its much simpler.

Comment: I think you still do need to scan the AppDomain - If you could just create an instance of a class this would be dynamic language

Comment: This might  be a literal description of what is occuring during the reflection process, however I don't think this answer is helpful to the OP because it does not practically demonstrate or explain how the steps you have outlined can be taken using the .net framework APIs

Comment: You're right, didn't know about that - this is still useful if you don't know or don't want to type out the namespace but yeah Type.GetType in the 99% scenario.

Comment: what if there is no namespace ?

Comment: @MonsterMMORPG it will still be in the appdomain so if you're scanning it should work