# How do I call a method on a static class if I've only got the classes string name?

Tags: c#, reflection

For example I have a list of strings that happen to be the names of static classes and depending on which string name is selected I just want to use that static class.  I know what the method is called on the static class, and it is the same on each class.

If the strings were "x", "y", "z" and the selected string is "z" and the method is called `process()`, then in my code it would call `x.process()` in some way, x being the name of an actual static class.

Remember these are `static` classes.

Comment: see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1418209/calling-a-method-on-a-static-class-given-its-type-name-and-method-names-as-stri

Comment: Consider following c# naming conventions for method names... Unlike Java/Javascript, method names should be in CapitalCamelCase (or PascalCase)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You would use reflection but include the `namespace` with the `class` name.

```
Type type = Type.GetType("namespace.x");
MethodInfo process = type.GetMethod("process");
process.Invoke(null, null);
```

Comment: @descf Do note that the class name probably won't be enough, you'll also need the namespace.

Comment: @Gabe It gets the type ok but not the method which remains null.

Comment: Then the method does not exist on the type. Make sure you're spelling it correctly, it's case sensitive. Make sure you're using the correct namespace too.

Comment: @Gabe The BindingFlags need to be set properly as well (in my case the class and the method are internal)