# Dynamically calling / invoking static method by it's name

Tags: c#

I have the current piece of code:

```
public static OrderDraft ParseImportFile(Int32 TemplateId, String FTPUser, String CSVFilePath, Boolean IgnoreError = false)
{
    // Init
    OrderDraft myOrderDraft = new OrderDraft();

    // Anticipate Error
    try
    {
        // Load Sync Template Info
        SyncTemplateInfo mySyncTemplateInfo = Utils.GetTemplateInfo(TemplateId, IgnoreError);

        // Switch On Selected Template
        switch (TemplateId)
        {
            // Template #1
            case 1:
                myOrderDraft = Parsers.Template1.Parse(FTPUser, CSVFilePath, mySyncTemplateInfo, IgnoreError);
                break;

            // Template #2
            case 2:
                myOrderDraft = Parsers.Template2.Parse(FTPUser, CSVFilePath, mySyncTemplateInfo, IgnoreError);
                break;
        }
    }
    catch { }

    // Finished
    return myOrderDraft;
}
```

Where `Parsers` is the name of the folder/namespace. `TemplateN` is the name of the class.

What I want to be able to do do is dynamically call the static method, instead of having a switch case and replicating the same code over and over (I might develop more than 10+ parsers).

Any idea how I can achieve this? I had a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/a/1418228/2332336 but I am not sure how I can do this for my own code...

Answer (score 0):

I hope the following might help

```
        string Parsers = "...";
        string TemplateN = "...";
        string MethodName = "...";

        var q = from t in Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes()
                where t.IsClass && t.Namespace == Parsers && t.Name == TemplateN
                select t;

        Type classType = null;

        foreach (var item in q)
        {
            classType = item;//select the first match
            break;
        }

        if (classType == null)
        {
            return; //no matched class
        }

        MethodInfo mf = classType.GetMethod(MethodName);

        if (mf  == null)
        {
            return; //no matched method
        }

        myOrderDraft = mf.Invoke(new object()/*Sender*/,new object[]{}/*parameters*/);
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion also. `classType` is null. same as above.